# Riccati Equation for falling particle.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

I'am trying to solve the differential equation for a falling particle of mass 1 with air resistance proportional to $v^2$ (v is velocity):
$$v'=g-v^2$$
This is a Riccati-Equation with stationary solution $\hat{v}=\sqrt{g}$, so we can transform it to the Bernoulli Equation
$$u'=-u^2-2\sqrt{g}u$$
Substituting $z=u^{-1}$ gives
$$\begin{align*}z'=2\sqrt{g}z+1\\
\Rightarrow z(t)=Ce^{2\sqrt{g}t}-\frac1{2\sqrt{g}}\\
\Rightarrow u(t)=\frac{1}{Ce^{2\sqrt{g}t}-\frac1{2\sqrt{g}}}\\
\Rightarrow v(t)=\frac{1}{Ce^{2\sqrt{g}t}-\frac1{2\sqrt{g}}}+\sqrt{g}\end{align*}$$

The problem is that this solution does not make physical sense to me, since its decreasing and does not match my reference solution.
Can you explain to me where I have gone wrong?

Comment: You might want to tell us your reference solution so we can see what you were expecting...

Comment: @Chappers The one Dr. Sonnhard Graubner postet below. This is intuitive because it aproaches the stationary solution.

Comment: Well, so does your answer. It is increasing if $C>0$. You can get from one solution to the other by choosing the right value of $C$ (or perhaps easier is to start from the tanh and fiddle about with $c_1$).

Comment: For $C=1$(and g=9) [Wolfram Alpha plots this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+1%2F%28e%5E%286t%29-1%2F6%29%2B3+from+0+to+10)

Comment: Oh, whoops. I meant $C<0$.

Comment: why do you need to transform $v' = g - v^2?$  it is separable and partial fraction decomposition readily allows you to integrate.

Comment: Glad you fixed the spelling of the name Riccati; in Italian, *ricatti* is the plural of *ricatto*, which means *blackmail*. `;-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\alpha \tanh \left(c_1 \alpha+\alpha t\right)=\alpha\frac{Be^{2t\alpha}-1}{Be^{2t\alpha}+1},\text{ with } B=e^{2c_1\alpha}$$

$$\frac{1}{Ce^{2t\alpha}-\frac{1}{2\alpha}}+\alpha=\alpha\left(\frac{2}{2C\alpha e^{2t\alpha}-1}+1\right)=\alpha\frac{1+2\alpha Ce^{2t\alpha}}{2C\alpha e^{2t\alpha}-1}=\alpha\frac{-1-2\alpha Ce^{2t\alpha}}{-2C\alpha e^{2t\alpha}+1}$$

Now put $C:=-\frac{B}{2\alpha}$ and...